# How to update the data type of same name multiple columns

Tags: sql-server, type-conversion

I have a column called 'LastModifiedDate' of 'smalldatetime' data type.

This column is present in almost all of my tables in the database.

I want to change this column to 'datetime' data type.

Is there any way to do that with a sql script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To generate a script you could do

```
SELECT 
   'ALTER TABLE  [' + Table_Schema + '].[' + Table_Name + '] ' + 
   'ALTER COLUMN [' + Column_Name  + '] DATETIME;'       

FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE COLUMN_NAME = 'LastModifiedDate'
```

Comment: Just what I wanted. Thank you, juergen d!